# Does angular-spinner work?

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to use [angular-spinner](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-spinner) with Angular JS 1.5.x in Chrome and every thing I try, every Plunker I find (even the one linked to the project page) fails with one error or another.

One discussion I found said I shouldn't load `spin.js` myself in a `<script>` tag but if I don't, how is it supposed to be loaded?  When I don't I get an error that `Spinner` (or `i` in the minimized code) isn't a constructor.  I feel like I must be missing something obvious but I've been searching and testing for hours and I don't feel any closer to a solution.

I actually don't care if I use *this* package, I just want a spinner so if `angular-spinner` is deprecated and there is a working alternative, I'm happy for the pointer.  Thanks.

Comment: *"One discussion I found said I shouldn't load spin.js myself in a <script> tag but if I don't, how is it supposed to be loaded?"* via an import statement as suggested in the usage section of the documentation you linked..?

Comment: I see "import 'angular-spinner';" but nothing about importing `spin.js`.

Comment: once the package is in your node_modules though, you should be able to import via the module name i.e Spinner (I assume is the name)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use version 2 of `spin.js`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//unpkg.com/spin.js@2"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//unpkg.com/angular-spinner"></script>
```

[The DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/Cjkp5aVQyr8PclTXtnxl?p=preview)

```js
var app = angular.module('myapp', ['angularSpinner']);
app.controller('MyController', ['$scope', 'usSpinnerService', '$rootScope',
  function($scope, usSpinnerService, $rootScope) {
    $scope.startcounter = 0;
    $scope.startSpin = function() {
      if (!$scope.spinneractive) {
        usSpinnerService.spin('spinner-1');
        $scope.startcounter++;
      }
    };

    $scope.stopSpin = function() {
      if ($scope.spinneractive) {
        usSpinnerService.stop('spinner-1');
      }
    };
    $scope.spinneractive = false;

    $rootScope.$on('us-spinner:spin', function(event, key) {
      $scope.spinneractive = true;
    });

    $rootScope.$on('us-spinner:stop', function(event, key) {
      $scope.spinneractive = false;
    });
  }
]);
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//unpkg.com/spin.js@2"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//unpkg.com/angular-spinner"></script>

<body ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="MyController">
  <h1>Hello Spinner!</h1>
  <input type="button" ng-click="startSpin()" value="Start spinner" />
  <input type="button" ng-click="stopSpin()" value="Stop spinner" />
  <br />Spinner active: {{spinneractive}}<br />Started: {{startcounter}} times<br />
  <span us-spinner="{radius:30, width:8, length: 16}" spinner-key="spinner-1"></span>
</body>
```

Comment: I can see that working at Plunkr.  I'll see if I can get it working in my app.  Thanks.

Comment: The spinner shows up as the page loads but doesn't disappear.  Perhaps I misunderstood but I thought `angular-spinner` hooked into page loading in a way that displayed the spinner while any HTTP request was outstanding and took it down when they were all satisfied.

Comment: The DEMO shows how to start and stop a spinner. If your code isn't starting and stopping your spinner as you desire, you need to create a new question with a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem.

Comment: Yes, the demo works.  And I can explicitly start and stop the spinner.  I was just expecting something automatic.  Perhaps that's the `angular-loading-spinner` package.

Answer (score 0):

There's a bug: https://github.com/urish/angular-spinner/issues/26 spinner keys won't work as intended.

What worked for me was registering every spinner in an array: when you call .spin(spinnerName) just add {spinnerName: true} to some controller's array, when you call stop(spinnerName) change it to {spinnerName: false}. Then show/hide the spinner with ng-if based on an expression like ng-if="mySpinners['spinnerName'] == true"